# Generating a tree of distinct integers results in a space leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, profiling

I want to generate a tree that contains distinct integers and find their sum. Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)

new = get <* modify' (+ 1)

tree :: Integer -> Tree Integer
tree n = evalState (go n) 0 where
    go 0 = Leaf <$> new
    go n = Branch <$> go (n - 1) <*> new <*> go (n - 1)

sumTree = go 0 where
    go !a (Leaf n)       = a + n
    go !a (Branch l n r) = go (go (a + n) l) r

main = print $ sumTree (tree 20)
```

Compiled with `-O2` it results in

```
     348,785,728 bytes allocated in the heap
     147,227,228 bytes copied during GC
      34,656,860 bytes maximum residency (13 sample(s))
          35,468 bytes maximum slop
              72 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       565 colls,     0 par    0.764s   1.024s     0.0018s    0.0071s
  Gen  1        13 colls,     0 par    0.936s   1.014s     0.0780s    0.3214s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.936s  (  0.764s elapsed)
  GC      time    1.700s  (  2.038s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  Total   time    2.636s  (  2.805s elapsed)

  %GC     time      64.5%  (72.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    372,631,936 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  35.5% of total user, 33.4% of total elapsed
```

Why am I getting this space leak? How to remove it?

Comment: `import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict` instead, since you can't use the weird extra laziness here. That seems the most likely problem. You may or may not actually benefit by that fancy `sumTree`, depending on how it leans (I think).

Comment: Er... I guess you *can* benefit from the extra laziness, but only with very great care in summing. I wouldn't generally recommend that approach--too fragile.

Comment: @dfeuer, that was the first thing I tried. It's slightly better, but there is still a leak. The [best version](http://lpaste.net/147785) I wrote uses both strict and lazy state (but without explicit `State`). Twice as fast, 27 MB total memory in use, but still half of the time spent on GC.

Comment: I think the best you can do is probably to use some math to figure out how to build the tree in a purely top-down fashion, without passing state, so the right subtree does not depend on any results produced building the left subtree. This will make the tree-building process as usefully lazy as possible, after which you can focus on how your sum function consumes the tree.

Comment: Your `sumTree` forces the left subtree (at least) because of `(a + n)` in the strict accumulator (`n` is output by the `State` computation that computes the left tree). If you write a `sumTree` without accumulator and switch to `Int`-s, it runs in 2 MB memory. I'm not sure though why `Integer` leaks space even in this case; I might look at it and write up an answer later coz' I'm busy now.

Comment: @András Kovács, thanks. Alternatively, `deriving (Foldable)` and `foldl' (+) 0` results in 2 MB too (and with `Integer`s too).

Comment: @AndrásKovács, that's why I consider the lazy state approach fragile.

Comment: Turns out `Integer` leaks space because it builds up the whole `(+)` thunk tree (the "classic" leak), while `Int` gets unboxed and made strict. A `seq` or bang pattern on the left sum repairs it. I agree it's rather fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you build a tree, you should try to find a way to work exclusively from the top down. This is generally good for laziness, concurrency, cache utilization, GC effectiveness, etc. The tree you build is just a complete binary tree numbered in order. I suggest you consider using the following signature and doing some bit shifting:

```
tree :: Bits b => Int -> Tree b
```

You can break out a helper function that takes the starting point.